# Doctrine 2 ObjectMultiCheckbox checked property

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I've got followed :
ZF2, Doctrine 2, many to many.

Question: how can i make checkboxes actually checked in view? Seems it can be done by using name convensions.
Can anybody give me advice please?

Relations are:

```
Portfolio.php
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Worker", inversedBy="portfolio")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="portfolio_workers",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="portfolio_id",referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="worker_id",referencedColumnName="id")}

 * )
 */
private $workers;
```

and

```
Worker.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Portfolio", mappedBy="workers")
 */
private $portfolio;
```

And also element add code is:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'workerId',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'TESTE',
            'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class'   => 'Backend\Entity\Worker',
            'property'       => 'name'
        )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all, seems like i've found solution. I've just changed form element code with following:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'workers',
    'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'TESTE',
        'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
        'target_class'   => 'Backend\Entity\Worker',
        'property'       => 'name'
    )
));
```

Maybe it can be helpful for sleepy guys like me)

Comment: So you just changed 'name' from 'workerID' to 'workers'?